# Add fake players on the tab

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to make a custom tab plugin. I want to add custom fake players in the tab, differents for each players, with packets so. By example player1 will recieve a packet taling him a player named "Money: 100" has connected and an other will recieve a player named "Money: 340". By making the plugin, I remarked the CraftPlayers bypasses the name restrictions. The PlayerListName (the Tab Name) can contain slashes (**/**), points (**.**), color (**§**), crochets (**[]**), spaces (** **) and other things.

So first, i found the `PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo`, i can initialize it like that `PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, EntityPlayer)`.

My problem ? I don't know how to initialize an Entity Player.

How can you help me ? Buy telling how can i initialize an Entity Player. **But**, of preference, how to create a CraftPlayer, because i have more liberty in the name, then make CraftPlayer#getHandle()

I think the CraftPlayer hasn't constructor, but i'm not sure of that?.

My actual code:

```
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        CraftPlayer craftPlayer = (CraftPlayer) player;
        craftPlayer.setPlayerListName(TabUsername.getTabUsername(player));
        PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, craftPlayer.getHandle());
    }
```

Then i'll make a `craftPlayer.getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet)`

Thanks for future help ^^

Edit: I found the solution

```
CraftServer craftServer = (CraftServer) Bukkit.getServer();
CraftWorld craftWorld = (CraftWorld) craftPlayer.getWorld();
WorldServer worldServer = craftWorld.getHandle();
PlayerInteractManager playerInteractManager = new PlayerInteractManager(worldServer);
MinecraftServer minecraftServer =  ((CraftServer) Bukkit.getServer()).getServer();
GameProfile gameProfile = new GameProfile(uuid, playerName);
EntityPlayer entityPlayer = new EntityPlayer(minecraftServer, worldServer, gameProfile, playerInteractManager);
CraftPlayer tabPlayer = new CraftPlayer(craftServer, entityPlayer);
PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, tabPlayer.getHandle());
craftPlayer.getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet);
tabPlayer.setPlayerListName(tabPlayerName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need an instance of EntityPlayer to do that. You can also look at [the protocol wiki](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Player_Info) which data is stored in the packet, write that data into an ByteBuf (PacketDataSerializer is the minecraft wrapper for this class).

But, if you wish to do it with an EntityPlayer you can create it with this constructor:

```java
public EntityPlayer(MinecraftServer minecraftserver, WorldServer worldserver, GameProfile gameprofile, PlayerInteractManager playerinteractmanager) {
```

You can get your needed parameters with this code:

```java
Location spawnLocation = commandSender.getLocation();
MinecraftServer server = ((CraftServer) Bukkit.getServer()).getServer();
WorldServer world = ((CraftWorld) spawnLocation.getWorld()).getHandle();
GameProfile gameProfile = new GameProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), "Test");
PlayerInteractManager playerInteractManager = new PlayerInteractManager(world);
    
EntityPlayer entityPlayer = new EntityPlayer(server, world, gameProfile, playerInteractManager);
```

Comment: I found the solution